# Div is larger than its contents

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I'm trying to place content below this datatables paging control, but the div is larger than its contents. This pushes my content down further than I want.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/32535/

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div style="display:inline;" class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 pt-3">
    <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="crfTable_paginate">
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li class="paginate_button previous disabled" id="crfTable_previous">
        <a href="#" aria-controls="crfTable" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0">Previous</a>
      </li>
      <li class="paginate_button active">
        <a href="#" aria-controls="crfTable" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="paginate_button next disabled" id="crfTable_next">
        <a href="#" aria-controls="crfTable" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">Next</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the relevant datatables css:

```
div.dataTables_paginate {
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: right;
}

div.dataTables_paginate ul.pagination {
    margin: 2px 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I've been poking around in both the chrome and firefox debuggers trying to find a style which is causing this, but it just says that the element is 43 pixels in height instead of the 38 (34 from the ul, with the 2 margin above and below) that it should be.

Any thoughts about what is causing this? Why would it lose the shrinkwrapping effect?

I've tried adding inline, as well as inline-block to the container div and a max-height:38, but nothing has removed that extra 5px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should write as below

> The `line-height` property defines the amount of space above and below inline elements.

```
div.dataTables_paginate ul.pagination {
    margin: 2px 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: That did not fix the fiddle.

Comment: You were on the right track, though. I went back and applied the line-height to the div.dataTables_paginate instead of the ul, and that fixed it.

Comment: Had the same issue on a `.selectize-control` div from [Selectize](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/). The height of the div was greater than its content by 5 px. The `line-height` trick worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly for your `col-sm-6 col-md-6 pt-3` div you need to remove that `display: inline`. And for `ul.pagination` set that it is `display: block` :

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 pt-3">
    <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="crfTable_paginate">
    <ul class="pagination" style="display:block">
      <li class="paginate_button previous disabled" id="crfTable_previous">
        <a href="#" aria-controls="crfTable" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0">Previous</a>
      </li>
      <li class="paginate_button active">
        <a href="#" aria-controls="crfTable" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="paginate_button next disabled" id="crfTable_next">
        <a href="#" aria-controls="crfTable" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">Next</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Including your setting for margin you will be overriding `20px 0` from bootstrap

Comment: This removed the extra space, but the ul margin is stacking up above the ul element. I might be able to work with that though.

Comment: Well your `maring: 2px 0` on .pagination eliminates big gap.

Comment: yes, it reduces the margin from 20 to 2, but display:block pulls the ul out of the margins so you don't see the bottom margin any more because it overlaps with the ul element. I would have to overwrite the 2px margin to 0 and apply the margin to the div instead, which might be fine. we'll see